# Função Escore, Hessiana e Newton Raphson da distribuição exponencial no R

Tags: r, regressão

Como encontrar o vetor escore e a matriz Hessiana no `R` para aplicar o método de `Newton Raphson` no código abaixo:

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")

#Função para simular variáveis aleatórias de uma modelo de regressão exponencial.

simula.exponencial <- function(formula, beta) {
  X <- model.matrix(formula)
  lambda <- exp(-X %*% beta)
  y <- rexp(nrow(X), lambda)
  return(data.frame(y = y, X))
}

set.seed(123)
n=10
cov <- seq(0, 5, length=n)
dados1 <- simula.exponencial(~cov, c(2,0.5))
dados1

## Função escore
escore <- function(par, formula, dados){
  mf <- model.frame(formula, dados)
  X <- model.matrix(formula, data=mf)
  esco <- ?????????
  return(drop(esco))
  }

## Hessiana

hessiano <- function(par, formula, dados){
  X <- model.matrix(formula, data=dados)
  mat <- matrix(0, nrow(X), nrow(X))
  diag(mat) <- ???????
  H <- ??????????
  return(H)
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi direito a sua pergunta. tem ago a ver com os `????`? Outra coisa: será que você poderia providenciar um exemplo menor que demonstre a sua dúvida? Quanto menor o programa, mais fácil para alguém responder  a pergunta. Melhor ainda se o seu programa nem precisar da barrinha de scroll :)

Comment: Ok hugomg, minha pergunta é sobre as partes com ??? sim, não consegui construir essas funções (Escore e Hessiana). Coloquei o programa todo pois acredito ser interessante para ajudar alguém com esse mesmo problema! Mas concordo com você e peço desculpas pelo tamanho do post!

Comment: @fsbmat, sua pergunta está muito ruim do jeito que está. Esse problema não é simplesmente encontrar um código, ele tem um aspecto teórico. Assim, minhas sugestões são 1) que você utilize o Latex e defina exatamente o modelo que você está amostrando, para ficar claro que você não está gerando os dados de forma inapropriada e 2) especifique teoricamente o que você quer encontrar, usando Latex se necessário. Veja que se for uma regressão exponencial eu poderia aplicar o log e utilizar os estimadores de máxima verossimilhança. Downvote aguardando alterações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi @FlavioBarros, agradeço seu retorno! Consegui resolver essa questão, peço desculpas pela demora em responder. O script de resposta é:

```
## Função escore
escore <- function(par, formula, dados){
mf <- model.frame(formula, dados)
X <- model.matrix(formula, data=mf)
esco <- crossprod((n*(t(X)*par)^(-1)-model.response(mf)), t(X))
return(drop(esco))
}

## Hessiana ("naïve")
hessiano <- function(par, formula, dados){
X <- model.matrix(formula, data=dados)
mat <- matrix(0, nrow(X), nrow(X))
diag(mat) <- -exp(X%*%par)
H <- n/par^2
return(H)
}
```

A mesma encontra no pdf do SINAPE do prof. Paulo Justiniano e outros: http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais:mcie-sinape-v12.pdf